# Как убрать картинку сзади svg

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

Появляется какая-то картинка сзади svg в chrome. Проверял в edge все также, но в IE нет никаких проблем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 17 15" xml:space="preserve">
<image overflow="visible" width="17" height="15" xlink:href="t.png"/>
<path fill="#FFF" d="M10.95.144c1.685-.496 2.984.27 3.577 1.179.673-.231 1.331-.481 2.011-.708a2.345 2.345 0 0 1-.857 1.768c.685.17 1.304-.491 1.304-.491-.169 1-1.006 1.788-1.563 2.024-.231 6.75-3.175 11.217-10.077 11.082h-.446c-.41 0-4.164-.46-4.898-1.887 2.271.196 3.893-.422 4.693-1.177-.96-.3-2.679-.477-2.979-2.95.349.106.564.228 1.19.119C1.705 8.247.374 7.53.448 5.33c.285.328 1.067.536 1.34.472C1.085 5.561-.182 2.442.894.85c1.818 1.854 3.735 3.606 7.152 3.773C8.254 2.33 9.183.793 10.95.144z"/>
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 16" xml:space="preserve">
<image overflow="visible" width="20" height="16" xlink:href="youtube.png"/>
<path fill="#FFF" d="M17 0H3C1.35 0 0 1.35 0 3v10c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h14c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3V3c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM6.027 11.998V4.002L15.014 8l-8.987 3.998z"/>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну вот же в коде t.png и youtube.png написаны - именно они и появляются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в вопросе код двух иконок svg: twitter, youtube, а также  в теге `<image>` ссылка на растровые изображения twitter, youtube.

Если вам растровые изображения не нужны, то удалите `<image>` из SVG.

Раз есть иконки  соц. сетей, то вы наверное  хотели сделать ссылки на них, с помощью иконок.

Ниже код с минимальной вёрсткой. Каждая иконка SVG, обёрнута ссылкой `<a>`

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-color:#505050;
}
svg {
margin:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 17 15" xml:space="preserve">

 <path fill="#fff" d="M10.95.144c1.685-.496 2.984.27 3.577 1.179.673-.231 1.331-.481 2.011-.708a2.345 2.345 0 0 1-.857 1.768c.685.17 1.304-.491 1.304-.491-.169 1-1.006 1.788-1.563 2.024-.231 6.75-3.175 11.217-10.077 11.082h-.446c-.41 0-4.164-.46-4.898-1.887 2.271.196 3.893-.422 4.693-1.177-.96-.3-2.679-.477-2.979-2.95.349.106.564.228 1.19.119C1.705 8.247.374 7.53.448 5.33c.285.328 1.067.536 1.34.472C1.085 5.561-.182 2.442.894.85c1.818 1.854 3.735 3.606 7.152 3.773C8.254 2.33 9.183.793 10.95.144z"/>  
</svg>
</a>
<a href="#">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 16" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#fff" d="M17 0H3C1.35 0 0 1.35 0 3v10c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h14c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3V3c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM6.027 11.998V4.002L15.014 8l-8.987 3.998z"/>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
```

**Вариант с изменением цвета иконок при :hover**

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-color:#505050;
}
svg {
margin:0.5em;
}
#twitter, #youtube {
transition:fill 0.5s;
}
#twitter:hover {
fill: skyblue;
}

#youtube:hover {
fill:#FF7777;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 17 15" xml:space="preserve">

 <path id="twitter" fill="#fff" d="M10.95.144c1.685-.496 2.984.27 3.577 1.179.673-.231 1.331-.481 2.011-.708a2.345 2.345 0 0 1-.857 1.768c.685.17 1.304-.491 1.304-.491-.169 1-1.006 1.788-1.563 2.024-.231 6.75-3.175 11.217-10.077 11.082h-.446c-.41 0-4.164-.46-4.898-1.887 2.271.196 3.893-.422 4.693-1.177-.96-.3-2.679-.477-2.979-2.95.349.106.564.228 1.19.119C1.705 8.247.374 7.53.448 5.33c.285.328 1.067.536 1.34.472C1.085 5.561-.182 2.442.894.85c1.818 1.854 3.735 3.606 7.152 3.773C8.254 2.33 9.183.793 10.95.144z"/>  
</svg>
</a>
<a href="#">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="16" viewBox="0 0 20 16" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="youtube" fill="#fff" d="M17 0H3C1.35 0 0 1.35 0 3v10c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h14c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3V3c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM6.027 11.998V4.002L15.014 8l-8.987 3.998z"/>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
```